# Narrowing down what I am scraping from a website using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, find, screen-scraping, page-inspector

I am trying to practice my python scraping for websites but am having trouble narrowing it down to a reasonable size without python not recognizing what I am asking for. For example, here is my code:

```py
import bs4
import requests

url = requests.get('https://ballotpedia.org/Alabama_Supreme_Court')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'html.parser')
y = soup.find('table')
print(y)
```

I am trying to scrape the names of the judges of the Alabama State Supreme Court, but with this code, I get far too much information. I have tried things such as (in row 6)

```py
y = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})`
```

but I get a message saying that the search finds no results.

Here is an image of the inspection of the webpage. I am aiming to get the thead to work in my code but am failing!

[image]
How can I specify to python that I want only the names of the judges?

Thank you very much!

Comment: can't you also just run find('a') inside y = soup.find('table') ? (or y[0] if you get a list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, I will do it like this way.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://ballotpedia.org/Alabama_Supreme_Court")[2]["Judge"]

print(df.to_list())
```

Output:

```
['Brad Mendheim', 'Kelli Wise', 'Michael Bolin', 'William Sellers', 'Sarah Stewart', 'Greg Shaw', 'Tommy Bryan', 'Jay Mitchell', 'Tom 
Parker']
```

> Now Moving back to the original `issue` to solve it as I personally love to fix the real issue without navigating to alternative solutions.

there's difference between `find` which will return only the first `element` but `find_all` will return a `list` of `elements`. Check the [Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree).

import directly `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` instead of `import bs4` as it's the [The DRY Principle](https://realpython.com/lessons/dry-principle/) of Python.

Leave `bs4` to handle the content as it's one of it's tasks in the back-ground. so instead of `r.text` use `r.content`

Now, we will deep into the `HTML` to select it:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("https://ballotpedia.org/Alabama_Supreme_Court")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')


print([item.text for item in soup.select(
    "table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter a")])
```

Now, you have to read about [CSS-Selection](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Output:

```
['Brad Mendheim', 'Kelli Wise', 'Michael Bolin', 'William Sellers', 'Sarah Stewart', 'Greg Shaw', 'Tommy Bryan', 'Jay Mitchell', 'Tom Parker']
```